# is it possible to restore back to an earlier date on my samsung tablet 2?

Tags: data-recovery

My app crashed. So I uninstalled and reinstalled it thinking that the progress would still be saved on the game, but it wasn't. Is there a way of going back to an earlier date like you can do on a normal PC?

Answer (score 2):

You mean like a Windows Restore Point that is created automatically? Android doesn't have this feature. What is normally done for Android devices is to create a manual backup that can be done using [nandroid](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nandroid) or a third-party application like [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup). Then, you restore those back-ups.

Comment: In short: the save games are gone.